# kableExtra: Dynamic add_header_above labeling

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, kableextra

I would like to create a pdf with rmarkdown. The PDF should contain a table. The table should have a dynamic column label.

The tabhead should display the calendar week.

However, the calendar week (e.g., KW29) is not displayed but the variable name "kw0".

What is my error?

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(lubridate)
options(knitr.table.format = "latex")
loadData <- function() {# load some data}

myData<- loadData ()

kw0 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()) - 1, sep = "")
kw1 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()), sep = "")
kw2 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()) + 1, sep = "")
kw3 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()) + 2, sep = "")


kable(myData, row.names = FALSE, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(
  full_width = TRUE,
  font_size = 14 
  )  %>% add_header_above(header = c(" " = 1, kw0 = 2, kw1 = 2, kw2 = 2, kw3 = 2))
```

I am glad about your advice.

Answer (score 14):

The header is a named character vector with colspan as values.

You have to assign the names of the vector with the function `names()`.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(lubridate)
options(knitr.table.format = "latex")
loadData <- function() {# load some data}

myData<- loadData ()

kw0 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()) - 1, sep = "")
kw1 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()), sep = "")
kw2 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()) + 1, sep = "")
kw3 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()) + 2, sep = "")

# Set a named vector for dynamic header

# create vector with colspan
myHeader <- c(" " = 2, kw0 = 2, kw1 = 2, kw2 = 2, kw3 = 2)

# set vector names 
names(myHeader) <- c(" ", kw0, kw1, kw2, kw3)

kable(myData, row.names = FALSE, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(
  full_width = TRUE,
  font_size = 14 
  )  %>% add_header_above(header = myHeader)
```

Comment: myHeader <- c(2, 2, 2) and names(myHeader) <- c("n1", "n2", "n3")

Answer (score 9):

An easy and quick method is described on the `kableExtra` developer's github page: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/415

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(lubridate)
options(knitr.table.format = "latex")
loadData <- function() {# load some data}

myData<- loadData ()

kw0 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()) - 1, sep = "")
kw1 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()), sep = "")
kw2 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()) + 1, sep = "")
kw3 <- paste("KW", week(Sys.Date()) + 2, sep = "")


kable(myData, row.names = FALSE, booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(
  full_width = TRUE,
  font_size = 14 
  )  %>% add_header_above(header = c(" " = 1, setNames(2,kw0), setNames(2,kw1), setNames(2,kw2), setNames(2,kw3))
```