# kableExtra: adjust font face and background of add_header_above()

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

In a table generated with `kableExtra()` I would like to adjust the font face and background of the two top rows added with `add_header_above()`.

The MWE provided below allows making adjustments to the top row of the original table.
However, my goal is that

- the upper top row added has a **bold** font face and a colored background, and
- the lower top row added has an *italic* font face.

The table is included in a Rmarkdown document which is knitted both to PDF/LaTex and HTML.

### MWE

```
mtcars[1:3,1:4] %>% kable() %>% 
    kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down")) %>% 
  # add column labels
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Features" = 2, "Features" = 2)) %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Properties A" = 2, "Properties B" = 2)) %>% 
  # adjust font face and backgroun
  row_spec(row = 0, italic = T) %>% 
  row_spec(row = 0, background = "orange")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While providing an answer for this related [post on SO on changing font size in kableExtra tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52001585/changing-the-font-size-of-headers-of-kableextra-table/62660374#62660374) for manually added header/grouping rows added with `add_header_above()`, I came across the solution to my own question.

`add_header_above()` actually provides many, many arguments to twist the output as desired:

```
add_header_above(kable_input, header = NULL, bold = FALSE,
  italic = FALSE, monospace = FALSE, underline = FALSE,
  strikeout = FALSE, align = "c", color = NULL, background = NULL,
  font_size = NULL, angle = NULL, escape = TRUE, line = TRUE,
  line_sep = 3, extra_css = NULL, include_empty = FALSE)
```

An illustrative MWE:

```
vec <- c("Properties A", "Properties B")
mtcars[1:3,1:4] %>% kable() %>% 
  kable_styling() %>% 
  # 2nd. level of grouping rows added on top of the table
  add_header_above(
    c(" " = 1, 
      "Features" = 2, 
      "Features" = 2), 
    font_size = 15, italic = TRUE) %>%
  # 1st. level of grouping rows added on top of the table (with dynamic labels as requested)
  add_header_above(
    c(" " = 1, 
      setNames(2, vec[1]),
      setNames(2, vec[1])), 
    font_size = 25, bold = TRUE, color = "orange", background = "lightblue") %>% 
  # adjust font face and background
  row_spec(row = 0, italic = T) %>% 
  row_spec(row = 0, background = "orange")
```

[image]