# How to correctly display footnote marker in header using kableExtra::kable() function in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I want to use `kable()` from the `kableExtra` package in R to add a footnote marker using the `footnote_marker_number()` function to a header item, specifically through the `add_header_above()` function. In this specific case, the documentation specifies that the `double_escape` argument is set to `TRUE`. I have done this, but I cannot get the table to properly display the footnote marker. Here is a reproducible example of what I tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

kw0 <- paste0("test",footnote_marker_number(1,double_escape = T))

mtcars %>%
  kbl("html",escape=F,booktabs=T) %>%
  add_header_above(header = c(" " = 6,
                   setNames(6,kw0))) %>%
  footnote(number = c("test"))
```

I expect to see the correct display of the marker, instead, I see `test<sup>1</sup>` in the table. I have looked at similar questions here on Stack Overflow ([kableExtra: Dynamic add_header_above labeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206908/kableextra-dynamic-add-header-above-labeling)) but this has not resolved the problem. Would appreciate any guidance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `escape = FALSE` to the `add_header_above` argument.

Here is the solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

kw0 <- paste0("test",footnote_marker_number(1, double_escape = T))

mtcars %>%
  kbl("html",escape=F,booktabs=T) %>%
  add_header_above(header = c(" " = 6,
                              setNames(6,kw0)), escape = F) %>%
  footnote(number = c("test"))
```

-output

[image]